# How to check live memory consumption of wildfly in ubuntu

Tags: linux, jboss, wildfly, jmap, jstat

I am using wildfly (JBOSS 9) as server for my java web application. But after some time i.e. almost 8-9 hours of usage the application becomes dead slow.

How can i check the live memory consumption of wildfly in terminal or on UI.

I am using Ubuntu 14

Comment: `man top` may help. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've created an admin user (by running add-user.sh in the bin directory) you can access the administration console at http://localhost:9990/console to see this information.  The console defaults to a different port - 9990 - than the "normal" 8080 port.  Once you're in, my 10.1 UI has me go to Runtime -> Standalone Server -> JVM -> View.  I'm not sure about Wildfly 9 but it should be similar.  Once there I can see memory and thread stats.